# Given two diagonal points, how to generate all coordinates forming a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given two diagonal points, how do I go about generating all the coordinates forming a rectangle?

[image]

For instance, the above two points will generate the coordinates like below in Javascript.

```
const firstPoint = [1, 3];
const secondPoint = [4, 1];

const result = [ 
    [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4],
    [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4],
    [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4],
];
```

You can safely assume that two points will not have the same x or y coordinates, since those conditions will not form a rectangle.

To summarize, how do I generate the result array above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several strategy to solve this problem, I can suggest the one I could use:

```js
// We first find the limits
const minX = Math.min(firstPoint[0], secondPoint[0]);
const maxX = Math.max(firstPoint[0], secondPoint[0]);
const minY = Math.min(firstPoint[1], secondPoint[1]);
const maxY = Math.max(firstPoint[1], secondPoint[1]);

const results = [];
// With this double nested for loop we find all the solutions are included in the limits
for (let x = minX; x <= maxX; x++) {
    for(let y = minY; y <= maxY; y++) {
        // Solution is combination of [x,y], we have just to add it to the results array
        results.push([x, y]);
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Such a simple and clean solution! Thank you so much.